# Can I use find for a writability test only for the name I pass it, without recursing?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

I have the below code which I'm just trying to print the permissions of user home directories in `/etc/passwd` file. I'm also trying to get only those directories only which have group and world write permissions.

I'm able to get the details of home directories, but was only able to print all the directories which are recursively there in the home directory. I only need to print values of home directories instead of recursively doing it.

```
for homdir in $(cat /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $6}'); do find $homdir -perm -o+w; done > /tmp/writeperimissions
```

I expect the output should print only group and world writable permissions of just the directories) into `/tmp/writeperimissions` (not recursively).

Comment: You should detail the problem or error you are encountering.

Comment: Note that [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) applies just as much to the output of a command substitution as it does to an actual file. (Not that this *necessarily* is the cause of your immediate bug, but it's certainly one of a set of issues with potential to result in generally unreliable code; lack of quoting on expansions is another).

Answer (score 1):

Use `-maxdepth 0` to match only the item itself. Thus:

```
while IFS=: read _ _ _ _ _ home _; do
  [[ -d $home ]] || continue # skip directories that do not actually exist
  find "$home" -maxdepth 0 -perm -o+w
done </etc/passwd | tee /tmp/world-writable-homedirs
```

When `read` is passed multiple arguments, it splits into fields on the character in `IFS` (in this case, `:`), and assigns each field to a variable named thusly. In this case, then, we assign the first five fields to variables named `_`, and the sixth to a variable named `home`.

Not passing `-r` to `read` tells it to treat `\:` as a literal `:`, so you can have users with colons in their human-readable name or GECOS fields without throwing off the parse; this actually makes the `read`-based parse more accurate than the `awk` one.